# How to send picture with whatsapp android

Tags: android, whatsapp

Hi everyone I'm an android develeloper and in my app I need to share an image with a text by whatsapp, the problem is that Uri method doesn't work anymore. This is Uri method:

```
 Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//Target whatsapp:
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
//Add text and then Image URI
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, picture_text);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

try {
    startActivity(shareIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
}
```

So is there any method different from this one?

Comment: The intent seems to be working fine for me. Can you give more details about what happens after the call to `startActivity`?

Comment: @cascal when i chose the contact in whatsapp, in place of the image there is a black screen and if i click on send button pop up a Toast that tell: sharing failed.